# How do change the string array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I am trying to add some column headers from an Excel sheet to a string[] but if I dont get 1 set of headers, I can assume it is the other set of headers that I need to define. Hopefully the code below shows it better than I can explain:

```
        string[] requiredHeaders = { "orderNo",
                                     "styleNo",
                                     "description",
                                     "size",
                                     "colour",
                                     "qtyPerCarton",
                                     "numberOfCartons",
                                     "total" };
        CurrentRow = 1;
        int headerRow = HeaderCheck(ref headerMap, requiredHeaders);
        //Check we have headers to pass before continuing
        if(headerRow != 0)
        {
            ProcessDeliveryNote(ref headerMap, headerRow);
        }
        else 
        {
            string[] requiredHeaders = { "description",
                                         "qtyPerCarton",
                                         "cartonWeight",
                                         "cartonSize",
                                         "noOfCartons",
                                         "totalNoOfUnits" };

            headerRow = HeaderCheck(ref headerMap, requiredHeaders);
            if(headerRow != 0)
```

At the second occurrence of string[] requiredHeaders I get the following error:
A local parameter named requiredHeaders cannot be declared in this scope because that name is being used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to define the variable named *requiredHeaders* twice. The second time you do not need to create it, because it already exist - you just have to assign a different value to it.

So instead of

```
string[] requiredHeaders = { "description",
    "qtyPerCarton",
    "cartonWeight",
    "cartonSize",
    "noOfCartons",
    "totalNoOfUnits"
};
```

use

```
requiredHeaders = new string[] { 
    "description",
    "qtyPerCarton",
    "cartonWeight",
    "cartonSize",
    "noOfCartons",
    "totalNoOfUnits"
};
```

This way you do not recreate *requiredHeaders*, but you create a new array and assign that to *requiredHeaders*.

Comment: If I do that, I get red squigglies on each of the commas and on the closing }
"Expected ;"

Comment: That edit has worked! thanks. I will mark as answered once the timer lets me

Answer (score 4):

You're declaring a second variable with a name already declared in the same scope. 
Either give the second variable a new name or remove the declaration and just do `requiredHeaders = new string[] { values here }`

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/simple-names-are-not-so-simple) a simple article that can give you an easy to understand explanation.